# How to sort dict by value

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a dict, that looks like:

```
{"dest_ip1":average_ping_time,"dest_ip2":average_ping_time,"dest_ip3:average_ping_time}
```

I want to sort it by value(average_ping_time), suppose `average_ping_time` of `dest_ip2` is less than `average_ping_time` of `dest_ip1` and less than `average_ping_time` of `dest_ip3`, after treatment it should be like:

```
[(ip2:ip2_ping_time),(ip1:ip1_ping_time),(ip3:ip3_ping_time)]
```

I have my Ansible task configured as:

```
- name: Create and add items to dictionary
    set_fact:
      all_hosts_average_ping_time: "{{ all_hosts_average_ping_time | default({}) | combine({item['ip'] : item['average_ping_time']}) }}"
    with_items:
    - { 'ip' : 'dest_ip1', 'average_ping_time' : 23.36  }
    - { 'ip' : 'dest_ip2', 'average_ping_time' : 24.79  }
    - { 'ip' : 'dest_ip3', 'average_ping_time' : 28.96  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Jinja2 plugin called dictsort](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#dictsort).

If you want to filter by the value:

```yaml
# example values
# dest_ip1: 5.0
# dest_ip2: 1.0
# dest_ip3: 3.0

- debug:
    msg: "{{ all_hosts_average_ping_time | dictsort(false, 'value') }}"
```

Using my example values, this results in:

```yaml
[
    "dest_ip2",
    1.0
],
[
    "dest_ip3",
    3.0
],
[
    "dest_ip1",
    5.0
]
```

If you want to reverse the order, simply add that statement to dictsort:

```yaml
dictsort(false, 'value', reverse=true)
```